# Windows8 init file .emacs can't be saved

Tags: emacs, windows-8

I installed emacs on my new windows 8 computer. When I wanted to build and save the init file windows 8 gives the message "enter the file name" ("Geben sie einen Dateinamen ein"). Obviously, windows 8 does not understand .xxxx . Does anyone has an idea how to cope with that?
Thanks
giordano

Emacs: GNU Emacs 24.3.1
Windows8: 6.2.92

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, but which directory are you trying to save the file to? (Windows will try to stop you writing to certain locations.)

Comment: I wanted to save .emacs in C:\Users\giordano\. On XP and win-7 I could save .emcas in this directory but not in win-8. If I name this file _emacs I can save it and I can work with Emacs which gives a warning: _emacs init file is depricated, please use .emacs.

Comment: This is happening when you tell Emacs to save the init file? Or are you trying to create the file outside of Emacs? It sounds like Windows 8 is trying to be "helpful", but I'd be a bit surprised if its file system doesn't handle filenames starting with a dot, so I'd expect Emacs to be able to write the file without problems.

Comment: @phils: That's it! I tried to create it outside of Emacs. Thanks for this hint. I could save it with Emacs.

Comment: Very good. I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Windows 8's file manager tries to be "helpful" when you ask it to create a new filename starting with a dot. However the filesystem itself has no problems with such names; so as long as you are saving to a directory for which you have appropriate permissions, all you need to do is create the file using an application which doesn't provide that kind of unwanted "help". Such as Emacs itself.